# How to add multiple entries in one field of Object?

Tags: visualforce

[image]

I want to bulis this type of structure in salesforce Object

Comment: What have you tried so far and how are planning to achieve this? Are you creating the Product record in apex, via visualforce, lightning, process builder etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really understand what you are trying to do, if you could breif a little, it will be appreciated.

Also,i am not sure if this link will help you,check the below link and let me know if this is what you were trying,and if yes then you are free to ask any doubts if any.
http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2012/04/10/convert-a-related-list-to-a-comma-separated-list/

Cheers